GCP Security Command Center Vulnerability findings
I am using Packer to generate multiple images for AWS, GCP, Azure, VMWare, Qemu and Hyper-V for Ubuntu OS.
Since it is agent based service, can I use it for scanning servers for the above listed platform.
If yes, please provide the references as well.

You need the enterprise level of Security Command Center to enable multi-cloud capability, you can check this docs for more info.
